# How correctly to assign a value

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

I need to assign a value of my sequence to parameter `id_nu`. How can I do it?

`sname` - name of the schema

When I try in such way,I got the below error

```
PROCEDURE proc_createUser(sname IN varchar2, uname IN varchar2,ts IN varchar2) 
 IS

id_nu number(6);

BEGIN

id_nu := sname.UsersSeq.NextVal;

-- something

END proc_createUser;
```

Comment: When you say "scheme", what you really mean is "schema" right?  Might render the question clearer if you used the standard terminology (and include the errors you say you're going to include).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE proc_createuser(sname IN VARCHAR2, 
                          uname IN VARCHAR2,
                          ts IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
     id_nu NUMBER(6);
     v_sql VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
     v_sql := 'SELECT '|| sname||'.UsersSeq.NextVal FROM dual';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO id_nu;
     dbms_output.put_line(id_nu);

END proc_createuser;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done in 11g where you can directly assign a sequence value to a variable. In earlier versions, you need to write like this -

```
PROCEDURE proc_createUser(sname IN varchar2, uname IN varchar2,ts IN varchar2) IS

id_nu number(6);

BEGIN


select sname.UsersSeq.NextVal into id_nu
from dual;

END proc_createUser;
```

Comment: No this don*t works. SNAME isn*t a name of sheme. It is a parameter that contains a name of scheme

Comment: A variable won't work there. You need to write the schema name if you want to resolve the schema. Anyway if you are working in the same schema then you need not write schema name. It should pick up UsersSeq.NextVal

Comment: Else you need to write a dynamic statement - 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '|| sname ||'.UsersSeq.NextVal into id_nu
from dual';

Comment: Yes. I understand this, but I need to specify a schema name.
I can*t use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE because it is package procedure.

Comment: I tried to do it in such way

cur_hdl integer;  
rows_processed integer;  
id_nu number(6);  
text varchar2(100);  
BEGIN  
text:= sname ||'.UsersSeq.NextVal';  
cur_hdl := dbms_sql.open_cursor;  
  dbms_sql.parse(cur_hdl, plbInsertUsers,dbms_sql.native);  
  rows_processed := dbms_sql.execute(cur_hdl);  
  FETCH curhdl INTO id_nu;  
  dbms_sql.close_cursor(cur_hdl);  

END;<br/>

But it doesn*t works.

Comment: There is no other way than using the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. And yes you can use execute immediate in procedure.

Comment: It is an ancient way of using a dynamic cursor. You do not need a cursor here since you are pulling only a single record.

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '' || sname ||'.UsersSeq.NextVal' INTO id_nu; 

This don*t works. I got the ora-00900 error